# how to deal with with invalid command error

Tags: tcl

With the following code, I am getting `invalid command name` error message.

**Code :**

```
set value 1
if {$value == 0} {
      set val [expr $val & 0xFFFFFEFF]
     } else {
      set val [expr $val | 0x100]
      puts "value= $val"
     }
```

**Error:**

```
invalid command name "else"
    while executing
"else {
```

What is wrong in the code ?

Comment: Where the variable `val` is defined ? With some dummy `val` value, the code is working fine.

Comment: You will get that `invalid command name "else"` when you have used `else` without `if` command.

Comment: val is taken as a simple variable only

Comment: are you sure that your `else` keyword and `closebrace` before `else` keyword are in same line ? There is rule `} else {` in `tcl`

Comment: The code you posted does not create the error you say it does. Can you please provide the _actual_ code that creates the error?

Answer (score 2):

The snippet

```
set value 1
if {$value == 0} {
      set val [expr $val & 0xFFFFFEFF]
     } else {
      set val [expr $val | 0x100]
      puts "value= $val"
     }
```

does not cause this error, but *this* snippet does:

```
set value 1
if {$value == 0} {
      set val [expr $val & 0xFFFFFEFF]
     }
     else {
      set val [expr $val | 0x100]
      puts "value= $val"
     }
```

This is because of the newline between the closing brace of the first `if` clause and the word `else`. I suspect you by mistake corrected the code yourself while posting it.

Comment: Same thing i mentioned in comment.. :) I also might suspecting the same thing that he has posted incorrect code..

Comment: @AxT_8041: yes, and Dinesh also brought it up. I thought it might be useful to illustrate the difference more clearly than possible in a comment. It's a common enough error.